# JMeter can't connect to local database

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter, centos6

I am trying to run a .jmx script to run locally on my CentOS machine.. I have it configured to connect as:

```
jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/test
```

With all the correct credentials (logging in as root). Everytime I run the script on CentOS command line:

```
./bin/jmeter.sh -Jusers=5000 -n -t ~/test.jmx -l results/test.log
```

I get this:

```
2015/12/14 20:11:28 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not load driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.configure(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:264)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.initPool(DataSourceElement.java:235)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.testStarted(DataSourceElement.java:108)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:214)
        at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:336)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've looked up a few things online and a lot of articles advised me to put the JDBC .jar file in it's lib/ folder. I have done that and it is still not working.. Is there anything else I should try?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have placed correct mysql-connector file in Lib folder. Issues may also come in case of version incompatibility between your mysql and mysql-connector.

You can download latest **mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar** from following URL: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Just take the JAR file from zip and place it your JMETER lib folder.

To properly configure MySQL JDBC connection refer to official JMeter documentation: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration